Custom pytest.fixture is running before pytest_addoption
I was using pytest==7.3.1 and decided to use pytest=8.2.1.
Currently I have faced the issue regarding:

no option named '--environment'

After investigation, appeared that custom pytest.fixture is called before pytest_addoption using pytest=8.2.1 which is difference from pytest=7.3.1 where pytest_addoption is called before pytest.fixture
Is that okay, or I have missed something in the documentation?
Code example for conftest.py:
class CLIOptions:
    ENVIRONMENT = "--environment"

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        CLIOptions.ENVIRONMENT,
        action="store",
        dest="environment",
        default="dev",
        choices=["local", "dev", "qa", "demo", "autopia", "vega"],
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def init_config(request: FixtureRequest):
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read(config_path)
    if config.get("Settings", "environment") != request.config.getoption(CLIOptions.ENVIRONMENT):
        config.set("Settings", "environment", request.config.getoption(CLIOptions.ENVIRONMENT))
        with open(os.path.join(parent_dir, "config/main_config.ini"), "w") as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)

Also during the debug it is appeared that there is no call for pytest_addoption at all. During tests run via Pycharm pytest_addoption is not called at all
I was investigating the documentation but didn't find any specific information about such issue or usage specific
